# Android studio Location Manager problem, not sure how to resolve the issue

Tags: java, android

I have watched multiple tutorials and followed this one on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O_7V6aEjgM

I do not understand why the location is not being tracked. Here is some of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TrackNet">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- above is the manifest file in my android studio project

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = location -> {
        txtLatitude.setText(location.getLatitude() + "");
        txtLongitude.setText(location.getLongitude() + "");

        if(location.hasAccuracy()){
            txtAccuracy.setText(location.getAccuracy() + "");
        }

        if(location.hasAltitude()){
            txtElevation.setText(location.getAltitude() + "");
        }

        if(location.hasSpeed()){
            txtSpeed.setText(location.getSpeed() + "");
        }

        radioButton = findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        if(location.hasSpeed() && location.hasAltitude() && location.hasAccuracy()){

            if(radioButton.getId() == R.id.switchLength){
                building.addCoordinateLength(new Coordinate(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),location.getAltitude(),location.getAccuracy(),""));
            }
            else if(radioButton.getId() == R.id.switchWidth){
                building.addCoordinateWidth(new Coordinate(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),location.getAltitude(),location.getAccuracy(),""));
            }
        }
        else{
            if(radioButton.getId() == R.id.switchLength){
                building.addCoordinateLength(new Coordinate(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),0,0,""));
            }
            else if(radioButton.getId() == R.id.switchWidth){
                building.addCoordinateWidth(new Coordinate(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),0,0,""));
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Coordinate Recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    };
```

---

- above is some code on the onCreate method. I am using buttons to request location updates via a button

Comment: Did you request permissions?

Comment: if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }
this code was before assigning locationManager